# why does pushing an element into an empty object hang up in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, firefox, loops

I have the following code:

```
var select_ids = [];
// syntax.filter.select_list is ["elem1", "elem2"]
for (var o = 0; o < syntax.filter.select_list.length; o += 1) {
    element = syntax.filter.select_list[o];
    if (priv.getPositionInArray(element,select_ids) === null ) {
      // this line hangs up the browser
      select_ids.unshift(element);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why push() or unshift() into an empty array when looping two iterations hangs up the browser for 3-4sec.

If I leave away this line:

```
select_ids.unshift(element);
```

the script runs instantly, so

**Question:**
why could push/unshift to an empty array produce such a delay? FYI, this is inside another loop with 3 iterations. For every parent loop I'm resetting select_ids to an empty object to fill.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
And I'm doing the if-clause to make sure I don't add doubles to the array.

**EDIT: (full code)**

```
priv.findBestIndexForQuery = function (indices, syntax) {
    var i, j, k, l, m, n, p, o, element,
      search_ids = [], select_ids = [], use_index = [],
      index, query_param, search_param,
      // need to parse into object
      current_query = jIO.ComplexQueries.parse(syntax.query);

    // loop indices
    for (i = 0; i < priv.indices.length; i += 1) {
      index = {};
      index.reference = priv.indices[i];
      index.reference_size = index.reference.fields.length;

      // rebuild for iteration
      if (current_query.query_list === undefined) {
        search_ids.push(current_query.id);
      } else {
        for (j = 0; j < current_query.query_list.length; j += 1) {
            if (priv.getPositionInArray(current_query.query_list[j].id, 
                search_ids) === null ) {
                search_ids.push(current_query.query_list[j].id);
            }
        }
      }
      for (o = 0; o < syntax.filter.select_list.length; o += 1) {
         element = syntax.filter.select_list[o];
         if (priv.getPositionInArray(element,select_ids) === null ) {
              // line causing problems
              select_ids.unshift(element);
         }
      }
// there is a lot more, but I'm hanging on the line above
}
```

**EDIT (getPostionInArray)**

```
  priv.getPositionInArray = function (element, array) {
     var i;
     for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        if (array[i] === element) {
           return i;
        }
     }
     return null;
  };
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Is it the same behaviour with all the browsers?

Comment: Firefox 16.0.2. Good point. Chrome runs normal.

Comment: Please show us the whole code (including the other loop), the initialisation of the `syntax` object and that `priv.getPositionInArray` function.

Comment: I really don't think '.unshift()' is the culprit. Instead of using 'priv.getPositionInArray' try 'select_ids.indexOf( element ) > -1'.

Comment: `. getPositionInArray()` is most likely the problem; please show its code.

Comment: @BGerrissen: ok. Faster... I will add my method. 1sec

Comment: And instead of 'o += 1', try 'o++' to avoid type coersion.

Comment: Yeh... the priv helper methods are definatly the culprit.

Comment: @BGerrissen: need to pass JSLint, so I can't use ++ without tweak JSLint options. Good point though

Comment: @frequent: it's, it seems [a bug in FF](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685204). @BGerrissen, type coersion is not the issue here, `++` and `+=` are identical

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: well spotted! Make it answer?

Comment: @Elias, afaik. '++' and '+=' are not identical, '++' is a number operator, '+=' is a concatenation operator that behaves differently depending on types (type coersion). Though I agree, it won't have much of an impact ;)

Comment: @BGerrissen `.length` is always an integer so in this case it won't make any difference.

Comment: @BGerrissen: they're not entirely the same, you're right... I should've added they are identical _in a for loop_, provided you use the variable only as a counter, but if you assign a string to it, you'd end up with an infinite loop or errors all over the place :)

Comment: That bug isn't a Firefox bug report.  Would you min posting a testcase somewhere that actually shows the problem, including the actual arguments passed to findBestIndexForQuery?  None of the things above should be triggering particularly slow behavior unless `select_ids` is ending up with a very large number of elements...

Comment: @BorisZbarsky: give me some time. I will try to set it up. Select_ids in my qunit test is maxium 3 elements, so this must not hang anywhere.

Comment: I just turned off Firebug and that seemed to do the trick. Now the script runs instantly. Still clueless though as to what is causing this.

Comment: Hmm.  Firebug being turned on turns off all sorts of optimizations, but still shouldn't cause this to take multiple seconds....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested by the OP, the issue is, indeed `unshift`: there have been bugs with this function (its context is ad-hoc) in the past, and [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685204) is still marked as *NEW*.

As for your `getPositionInArray` function, why don't you use the standard `indexOf` method? Most browsers support it, and for those that don't you can always add this to your script:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(search)
    {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        {
            if (this[i] === search)
            {//I use type & value check...
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;//-1 is the standard behaviour
    };
}
```

Or, if you want this method to return `null`, instead of `-1` in all browsers:

```
Array.prototype.indexOf = (function (nativeFunc)
{
    return function(search)
    {
        var retVal = nativeFunc.apply(this,[search]);//use native method
        return (retVal === -1 ? null : retVal);//return null if the native method returned -1
    };
}(Array.prototype.indexOf));//pass initial method to IIFE
```

Just a side-note, some prototype fun :)

Comment: @frequent: It's not that hard, though:). Anyhow, with the first snippet alone, you can just use `myArray.indexOf(element)` safely, even in IE, if it returns -1, the element doesn't exist, if it returns anything > -1, it does... the upside is, that on most browsers it's actually faster than what you're currently doing

Comment: this bug is really strange... I thought I fixed it by adding a "fake" element to the empty array, such as `["fake"]` and then working with it. I can add and remove other elements all right, So when I end up with ["fake"] again, I'm testing for array.length === 1 and the browser hangs again...

Comment: @frequent: Perhaps the only way to get around any unexpected behaviour would be to use `array[array.length] = 'new Value';`. Of course that doesn't `unshift` the array, for that: `array = ['new Value'].concat(array);` will have to do

Comment: That bug report has nothing to do with Firefox.  It's a bug report for Tamarin, which was the JS JIT that Flash and Firefox were considering sharing at some point.